# Can I display same activity for external displays on raspberry pi android using java

Tags: java, android, raspberry-pi4

I aim to achieve the setup depicted in the following image: [Application work for external displays connection on raspberry pi 4+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/On1u6.png)

My goal is to create an application that functions exclusively on Raspberry Pi. The primary objective is to set up three monitors in a car for different purposes:

1. Display 1: To show motor indicators and other relevant information.
2. Display 2: The central unit responsible for displaying maps, GPS, multimedia, and other services.
3. Display 3: A smaller static monitor dedicated to showing gear status and engine information.

Apologies for any language shortcomings.

Comment: Ok, but what is your question? Did you see the [tour]? Questions here need to be focused on a particular problem (see [ask]). Yours looks like you want someone to write that code for you, or provide the tutorials for that, which is off-topic and could be solved faster with a web search.